# Material Quality Managment View ( Inspection Setup using BAPI / Function Module )

Tags: abap

Inspection setup are created/updated/deleted inside quality managment view of material.I would like to create / update / Delete inspection setup using BAPI / Function Module based on certain conditions. The simple requirement can be implented using BDC but condition this is not possible and BDC ABAP progream will become more complex and difficult to handle.

I would like to know experts advise for create / updating / deleting inspection setup of material quality managment view using BAPI / Function Module.

Comment: Inspection setup ? You want to programatically do customizing stuff ?
Or do You mean, "inspection lot" ?

Comment: This is not customizing stuff. Follow steps for inspection setup. 1. Go to transaction MM01. 2. Select Quality Managmenet view 3. Enter Plant 4. You will see inspeciton setup button.

Comment: Ok, which steps in which transaction define the process ?

Comment: 1. Go to transaction MM01. 2. Select Quality Managmenet view 3. Enter Plant 4. You will see inspeciton setup button.

Comment: Got You. So, what ever happens behind this button, is, what You want to achieve via code ?

Comment: you can setup inspection. I have explained you process. I want to achieve same with function module / BAPI.

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inspection types can be created / deleted / updated with **BAPI** **BAPI_MATINSPCTRL_SAVEREPLICA**  .

Answer (score 0):

*QPLS_MATERIAL_INSPECT_UPDATE*

This module and it's friends take care of the related work, read their documentations.

Anyway, You could have find out by Yourself during debugging.

Not quite the proper way to ask/answer as a senior consultant... I'd say.

Comment: Please let me know where is the documentation available for the Function Module **QPLS_MATERIAL_INSPECT_UPDATE**.  Debugging is not the recommend way for finding solution. Can you please elaborate what is the proper way to ask/answer.